# How to create jira project using api

Tags: rest, jira

How to create Jira project using API? I tried the following but it is not working

```
curl -X POST -H --basic --user "user:password"\
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
 https://abc-jira.com/rest/api/2/project \
 -d '{
 "key": "yur",
 "name": "yur",
 "projectTypeKey": "software",
 "Project description": "yur",
 "avatarId": 10200
 }'
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: As mentioned before, could you post an error message? If I should guess, then change the field key `"Project description"` to only `"description"` and remove the field `"avatarId"` and it should work.